# How to write a single Makefile for a project with several folders?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I have the following **project structure** (I got this simply running `$ tree src`):

```
src
├── client
│   ├── client.c
│   ├── client_functions.c
│   ├── client_functions.h
├── common
│   ├── conf.c
│   ├── conf.h
│   ├── file_list.c
│   └── file_list.h
├── Makefile
└── server
    ├── server.c
    ├── server_functions.c
    └── server_functions.h
```

I want to have a single `Makefile` in the root `src` folder (therefore running a single `$ make` command for the whole project).

Here are **dependencies** (note that each `*.c` depends on the relative `*.h`):

- `client.c` depends on `client_functions.h`
- `client_functions.c` depends on `conf.h`
- `server.c` depends on `server_functions.c`
- `server_functions.c` depends on both `conf.h` and `file_list.h`

I'm trying to write a `Makefile` but I keep getting errors. I never created one for such a complex project structure (usally everything was in a single folder). Here's the first part of the `Makefile`:

```
CC := /usr/bin/gcc
RM := /usr/bin/rm -f
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3
```

**How should I write the rest of the `Makefile`**?

Note that I want only 2 executables: `client` inside the `client` folder and `server` inside the `server` folder.

**EDIT:** taking in consideration @melpomene answer, I wrote the following `Makefile`

```
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3
SRC := client/client.c client/client_functions.c client/client_functions.h server/server.c server/server_functions.c server/server_functions.h common/conf.c common/conf.h common/file_list.c common/file_list.h
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)

.PHONY: all

all: client/client server/server

client/client: client/client.o client/client_functions.o common/conf.o

client/client.o: client/client.c client/client_functions.h
client/client_functions.o: client/client_functions.c client/client_functions.h common/conf.h

server/server: server/server.o server/server_functions.o common/conf.o common/file_list.o

server/server.o: server/server.c server/server_functions.h
server/server_functions.o: server/server_functions.c server/server_functions.h common/conf.h common/file_list.h

common/conf.o: common/conf.c common/conf.h
common/file_list.o: common/file_list.c common/file_list.h

clean:
        rm -f client/*.o server/*.o common/*.o core

cleanall:
        rm -f client/*.o server/*.o common/*.o core client/client server/server
```

That now results in the following output:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3   -c -o client/client.o client/client.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3   -c -o client/client_functions.o client/client_functions.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -O3   -c -o common/conf.o common/conf.c
gcc   client/client.o client/client_functions.o common/conf.o   -o client/client
common/conf.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `at'
client/client_functions.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
common/conf.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `T'
client/client_functions.o:(.rodata+0x4): first defined here
common/conf.o:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `N'
client/client_functions.o:(.rodata+0x8): first defined here
common/conf.o:(.rodata+0x10): multiple definition of `p'
client/client_functions.o:(.rodata+0x10): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'client/client' failed
make: *** [client/client] Error 1
```

`at`, `T`, `N` and `p` are all variables defined in `conf.h`

Comment: Your dependency list is probably wrong/incomplete. E.g. `client_functions.c` should probably depend on `client_functions.h`, `server.c` shouldn't depend on `server_functions.c` (or any `.c` files), `conf.c`/`file_list.c` are currently unused, etc.

Comment: @melpomene I added this:  __(note that each `*.c` depends on the relative `*.h`)__

Comment: Don't define variables or functions in header files. http://c-faq.com/decl/decldef.html

Comment: @melpomene moving the definition of variables to `conf.c` indeed worked! Even if I honestly don't get why

Comment: @Robb1,  Real simple why... when variables are declared in a header file, then a instance of that variable is declared every time the header file is included

Comment: Your makefile, should have the following statements, in addition to `.PHONY: all`      `.PHONY: clean`   and `.PHONY: cleanall`

Comment: the 'recipe' for each of the targets: `clean:` and `cleanall:` should use the macro: `$(RM)`  rather than writing the actual command over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this is all you need:

```
.PHONY: all

all: client/client server/server

client/client: client/client.o client/client_functions.o common/conf.o

client/client.o: client/client.c client/client_functions.h
client/client_functions.o: client/client_functions.c client/client_functions.h common/conf.h

server/server: server/server.o server/server_functions.o common/conf.o common/file_list.o

server/server.o: server/server.c server/server_functions.h
server/server_functions.o: server/server_functions.c server/server_functions.h common/conf.h common/file_list.h

common/conf.o: common/conf.c common/conf.h
common/file_list.o: common/file_list.c common/file_list.h
```

I've listed all the dependencies you've described (modified by some educated guessing). The built-in implicit rules should do the rest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apparently I still have some little problem, but I don't get why: I edited the OP!

Comment: @Robb1 Did you try my unmodified makefile?